# What is an alternative to storing externally provided functions in Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

#### Background

I'm creating some kind of React layouting library that stores its current state in a Redux store.
The library isn't just a styling thing, it has certain (for this question irrelevant) capabilities.

However, since it's a layouting library, the consumer of the library will provide what to render at certain locations.

The library would be exposed thru a single slice (with corresponding reducers, actions and selectors) that the consumer is supposed to simply inject into their root reducer.

#### Current implementation

Currently, the way the library knows what to render is by the consumer providing the rendering function.

```
import { register } from "layouting-lib"
// ... other imports

function CustomContent() {
  return <div> Some consumer-determined content </div>
}

// and then the consumer registers this with the library's (redux) store

dispatch(
    // register is an action creator
    register("apn-container", () => <CustomContent />)
)
```

This way the library knows that the consumer wants the `<CustomContent />` component rendered into the `apn-container` (it doesn't really matter what that is).

#### ❓ The problem

As you know, [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) says that the functions should not be used in the state (or actions) as they are not serializable.

So, what other approach can I take so that my library *remembers* `HOW` to render the content when it does its layouting, so that I can properly use the goodies redux provides (history in devtools being the most important to me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint for the solution I've found is basically in the Redux documentation itself.

They suggest **intercepting** the **unserializable data** in the **middleware** and removing it from the action so that nothing unserializable ends up in the reducer.

In my case, it is totally fine if these rendering functions reside in the middleware.
The `register` action will scrape the function, store it in the middleware and forward the action without it.

And since all the `registers` should happen before the first render of the app anyway, it will work even with the redux devtools goodies.